# Runtime Error 6: OverFlow, in vb6 code execution time

Tags: vb6

I am getting Runtime error 6 Overflow when iam executing my vb6 application.
i am getting this error on this line.

```
Sections("Section5").Controls("lblcap").Caption = Format(((lTotOperMins - KPIDown) / lTotOperMins) * 100, "#0.00")
```

the values `lTotOperMins=0 , KPIDown=0 ,` and `Data Types` as `Long`
what is wrong with this code. Suggest me, i am not familiar to VB6.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting an overflow error, but the problem is lTotOperMins = 0. You cannot divide by 0.

Comment: Yes,But what is the solution when i need to pass that values ?

Comment: If lTotOperMins = 0 then `Sections("Section5").Controls("lblcap").Caption = "0"`?

Answer (score 3):

As jac said, it's because you're not checking first for a division by zero. I know that seems misleading because you're not getting that error, you're getting an Overflow.

As to why you're getting that instead of a division by zero is not something I'm awake enough to think deeply about, but simply checking first fixes the overflow. Here is an example resulting in an overflow followed by a working example with no errors:

#### Edit:### see very bottom showing how dividing TWO zeros results in an overflow, if one number is not 0 then it becomes a division by 0 error. Code at bottom.

#### Overflow error:

Image showing where overflow is occurring (can't upload, not enough reputation):

[Click to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrwQi.png)

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim lTotOperMins As Long, KPIDown As Long
  Dim lonDifference As Long

  lTotOperMins = 0
  KPIDown = 0

  ' Prevent / by 0
  lonDifference = lTotOperMins - KPIDown

  'If 0 = lonDifference Then
    'Label1.Caption = Format(0, "#0.00")
  'Else
    Label1.Caption = Format(((lonDifference) / lTotOperMins) * 100, "#0.00")
  'End If

End Sub
```

#### Working example:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim lTotOperMins As Long, KPIDown As Long
  Dim lonDifference As Long

  lTotOperMins = 0
  KPIDown = 0

  ' Prevent / by 0
  lonDifference = lTotOperMins - KPIDown

  If 0 = lonDifference Then
    Label1.Caption = "0.00"
  Else
    Label1.Caption = Format(((lonDifference) / lTotOperMins) * 100, "#0.00")
  End If

End Sub
```

#### Dividing two zeros results in overflow error

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim a As Long, b As Long

  a = 0
  b = 0

  Debug.Print a / b
End Sub
```

Comment: @user3463529: You should mark Daniel's answer as correct.